# Git author changes not being displayed in Git log

Tags: git

So, I've updated an old repo's author (my old account) with my new Author info using the following command:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
        if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = "<Old name>" ];
then
                GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="<New Name>";
                GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="<New Name>";
                GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="<New Email>";
                GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="<New Email>";
                git commit-tree "$@";
else
                git commit-tree "$@";
        fi' HEAD
```

However, when I  type git log I see the old Author name still on each commit. I also see the old author name in gitk --all

What am I doing wrong?

How can I get this overwritten so that my new author name and info is displayed in git log as well as commit history?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the output when you run that command? Tried it and it worked for me. I noticed you have a non-breaking space after "HEAD" which could mess up some commands but it didn't seem to be an issue for me.

Comment: Maybe the question is, what's the difference between committer name, author name, committer email and author email? And perhaps the committer name <old name> syntax is wrong.. I've put Jack Jones <jack@jones.com> here.. what should I be putting? Just Jack Jones?

Comment: Yes, the AUTHOR and COMMITTER names omit the email part.

Comment: @Apane101 Why have you deleted the question? This question is completely meaningless now.

Comment: Please do not deface your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And perhaps the committer name  syntax is wrong.
>   I've put `Jack Jones <jack@jones.com>` here.. what should I be putting? Just Jack Jones?

Yes, the email part should be in `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL`.
`GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` should be `"Jack Jones"` only.

The [OP Apane101](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1975127/apane101) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29497139/git-author-changes-not-being-displayed-in-git-log/29498367?noredirect=1#comment47157742_29498367):

> `rm .git/refs/original/refs/heads/develop` (or `gitk --all` would still show the old commits)

Comment: +1 We're getting closer, the only problem is now that it's doubled up. For example in gitk --all I see the new name author, but when I scroll down I see the exact commits from old author.. How do I reconcile this? And make it just new author records

Comment: Side question/possible solution. Can I remove all commits from my old account/old author and just keep the new renamed duplicate ones?

Comment: @Apane101 you should try first on a fresh clone of your repo (for multiple tests without breaking everything). Or at least you should reset your repo to your old HEAD (before git filtering) which you should see since gitk shows it to you.

Comment: Solved.. solution was : @rm .git/refs/original/refs/heads/develop

Comment: @Apane101 OK, I have included your finding  in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @Apane101 it would be best to leave the original question in place instead of replacing it with the answer. (That is what "answers" are for).